# AngularJS not updating binding when using routes

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, callback, scope

I am trying to get a small angularJS app running. The app should receive asynchronous messages via STOMP / Websockets. If a message via the web socket arrives, the angular app is supposed to display a changed value in the UI. In general angular's data binding works as expected, but if the scope is updated within the callback function `on_message()` nothing happens in the UI. I have read various post on similar topics and tried the suggested solutions like using $apply within the callback function, but without success.

In the debugger I can see that the $scope.SoC gets assigned the correct value, but the UI remains unchanged.

If the function `on_message(m)` is called directly - just for testing - and not from socket-client, the UI gets updated correctly.

This is the abbreviated structure of the controller code

```
App.controller('showCaseDataCtrl', function($scope){
var mySoC = 0.7;
$scope.status = {statusMessage: "No Message", SoC: 0.77, power: 5.4, numDevices: 89};

function on_message(m) {
    mySoC ++;
    $scope.$apply(function() {$scope.status.SoC = mySoC;});
    console.log(mySoC);
}
});
```

This is the HTML

```
<html ng-app="App">
...
<div class="col-md-4" >
      <h1> <span ng-bind="status.SoC" /> SoC</h1>
      <p>Charge Status</p>
</div>
...
</html>
```

Any suggestions what else to try are appreciated.

Update:

The problem has to to with mg-route and a separate view in the main HTML

in the main HTML I am using a statement like

```
<!-- views selected by the route will be injected here -->
<div ng-view ="" </div>
```

and the route provider looks like

```
App.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/',
        {
            controller: 'showCaseDataCtrl', 
            templateUrl: 'partials/Overview.html'
        })
      .when('/test',
        {
            controller: 'showCaseDataCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'partials/Overview.html'
        })
      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});
```

Removing the route provider and putting all HTML directly in the main HTML with

```
<div ng-controller="showCaseDataCtrl" class="col-md-4" >
  <h1> <span ng-bind="status.SoC" /> SoC</h1>
  <p>Charge Status</p>
</div>
```

solved the problem.

--- But I have no clue why ---

Any explanation appreciated

Comment: you need to wrap it in a `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: Tried that. did not work. I commented it out.

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket on the span tag in your HTML. I assumed that's a mistranscription in your pseudocode and not in your development code but thought it was worth a shot.

Comment: No errors appear in the debugger when you call on_message via your socket code?

Comment: no. no errors in the denugger. just the console.log

Comment: @mark. thanks for the hint. the bracket is there in real world.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `$scope` is not updating is because the callback is happening outside of Angular's $digest() cycle. Try wrapping it in $scope.$apply.

```
function on_message(m) {
    // console.log('Received:' + m);
    // var MyJSON = $.parseJSON(m.body);
    mySoC ++;
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.SoC = mySoC;
    });

    console.log(mySoC);
}
});
```

Seems like you had it commented out, but that should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I commented it out, since it did not work :-(